# ERC20 Tokens Transferred Information from Transaction Hash

Tags: php, ethereum, web3js, erc20, etherscan

EtherScan provides a API for transaction details It's part of Geth/Parity Proxy APIs by name eth_getTransactionByHash, But I am unable to get information what ERC20 token was transferred and how many.

I need Token Details and Number of token transferred with the help of Transaction Hash.
[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using the wrong API.

To get an ERC20 transfer's information, you need the transaction receipt, since transfer information is recorded in a transfer event log. You should be using `eth_getTransactionReceipt`.

This will give you a response such as this, for [this](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionReceipt&txhash=0x3265c1461d3f167c756fbc062ae3a2dc279b44a9c3ca2194271d4251cd0c1655&apikey=YourApiKeyToken) tx:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": {
    "blockHash": "0xc5e5a515898983d1370d40b03fc05ae08be861af746a1577796153a149a1bb20",
    "blockNumber": "0x5ff5dd",
    "contractAddress": null,
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "0xe85fb",
    "from": "0xd7afd4441fccc118b9207b0e136f4ef9319b3c79",
    "gasUsed": "0x9034",
    "logs": [
      {
        "address": "0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef",
        "topics": [
          "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
          "0x000000000000000000000000d7afd4441fccc118b9207b0e136f4ef9319b3c79",
          "0x00000000000000000000000069d9e9aff57ec73582ad1ce441726dba7ea78fe0"
        ],
        "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001054aefee8ba6d00000",
        "blockNumber": "0x5ff5dd",
        "transactionHash": "0x3265c1461d3f167c756fbc062ae3a2dc279b44a9c3ca2194271d4251cd0c1655",
        "transactionIndex": "0x1b",
        "blockHash": "0xc5e5a515898983d1370d40b03fc05ae08be861af746a1577796153a149a1bb20",
        "logIndex": "0xa",
        "removed": false
      }
    ],
    "logsBloom": "0x04000000002000000200000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "status": "0x1",
    "to": "0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef",
    "transactionHash": "0x3265c1461d3f167c756fbc062ae3a2dc279b44a9c3ca2194271d4251cd0c1655",
    "transactionIndex": "0x1b"
  }
}
```

Of this, this logs section is important.

The format of an ERC20 transfer log is `Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value)`. When you take the `keccak` hash for `Transfer(address,address,uint256)`, you get `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef` for the topic, as shown in the response above.

The next two value in that log are the `from` and `to` addresses respectively, packed as normal for ETH (zero padded until 32 bytes). Lastly, the `data` within the log is the value of the ERC20 token that was transferred (BAT in this example).

The `address` that emits the log, `0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef` in this case, is the token contract. You can then read the token symbol, name, and decimals from this contract using `eth_call` API to read the token information.

Comment: "When you take the keccak hash for Transfer(address,address,uint256), you get 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef" This has just helped me so much, thank  you!

Comment: On a side note, is there an easy way to find the other Keccak hashes for other function logs?